Cursor is turned around in a weird way when sculpting
Here's the screenshots. The cursor should look like a circle, like it usually does, but not this time for some reason.

And when I sculpt it sculpts in lines, not in circles

How do I turn the cursor back into a circle?

This can happen if your mesh has unapplied scaling that isn't uniform across the axes.  In object mode, try CtrlA and apply the scale, then switch back to sculpting mode and hopefully your brush will be back to a circle.

It worked, thanks!
